# conditional plotting not working as expected in a shiny document

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to make shiny documents in which the reader can choose between different versions of a graphs/table.

The first example works fine, but the second example only works if option two is selected.  Only difference is if{}else{} vs if{}if{} structure.

would like for the user to choose a few graphs rather than just one or two.

````
---
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---


#```{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
  selectInput("option",
    label = "Number of bins:",
    choices = c(1, 2, 3), selected = 1
  ),
)

renderUI({
  if (input$option == 1) {
    renderPlot({
      plot(1:10)
    })
  } else {
    renderPlot({
      plot(1:10, 10:1)
    })
  }
})
#```

#```{r eruptions2, echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
  selectInput("option2",
    label = "Number of bins:",
    choices = c(1, 2, 3), selected = 1
  ),
)

renderUI({
  if (input$option2 == 1) {
    renderPlot({
      plot(1:10)
    })
  }
  if (input$option2 == 2) {
    renderPlot({
      plot(1:10, 10:1)
    })
  }
})
````

Answer (score 1):

```r
renderUI({
  if (input$option2 == 1) {
    renderPlot({
      plot(1:10)
    })
  }
  if (input$option2 == 2) {
    renderPlot({
      plot(1:10, 10:1)
    })
  }
})
```

R executes the last statement of the expression between the curly braces. If `input$option2 == 1`, it continues to read the code, the one with `if(input$option == 2)`. Since this condition is not realized, the output is `NULL` (invisibly).

```r
> x <- if(2==3) {print(4)}
> x
NULL
```

Is it clear?

Comment: Yes after thinking about.  It seems a more robust solution is to create a "doWhat" function and pass input$option to it.  Many thanks.